# Spring @Autowired fails when ApplicationContext is inside another context

Tags: java, spring, autowired, applicationcontext

I'm trying to put together an SDK that uses Spring internally through a context it manages of its own. I want the jar that gets built to be usable regardless of whether or not Spring is in use on the application that wants to use the SDK.

I have something that works when it is running on its own. However if I attempt to use the SDK inside another Spring context (in my case a Spring Boot based application) I get a `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type` exception.

Try as I might I cannot understand how to get this working, or indeed what I am doing wrong. The classes below show what I'm doing, the org.example.testapp.MySDKTest fails with the exception while the org.example.test.MySDKTest successfully passes. Sorry there is so much code but I can't reproduce the issue with a simplified case.

**SDK source**

```
package org.example.mysdk;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import org.example.mysdk.MyService;
import org.example.mysdk.MyServiceConfiguration;

public final class MySDK {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static <T extends MyService> T getService(Class<? extends MyService> clazz, MyServiceConfiguration configuration) {
        T tmp = (T) getApplicationContext().getBean(clazz);
        tmp.setConfiguration(configuration);
        return tmp;
    }

    private static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        if (applicationContext == null) {
            applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringContext.class);
        }
        return applicationContext;
    }
}
```

.

```
package org.example.mysdk;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public abstract class MyService {

    private MyServiceConfiguration configuration;

    @Autowired
    private MyAutowiredService myAutowiredService;

    MyService() {
    }

    MyService(MyServiceConfiguration configuration) {
        super();
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public MyServiceConfiguration getConfiguration() {
        return configuration;
    }

    void setConfiguration(MyServiceConfiguration configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    String getSomething(String in) {
        return "something + " + myAutowiredService.getThing(configuration.getValue()) + " and " + in;
    }
}
```

.

```
package org.example.mysdk;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyServiceImpl1 extends MyService {

    public MyServiceImpl1() {
    }

    public MyServiceImpl1(MyServiceConfiguration configuration) {
        super(configuration);
    }

    public String method1() {
        return this.getSomething("method1");
    }

}
```

.

```
package org.example.mysdk;

public class MyServiceConfiguration {

    private String value;

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

.

```
package org.example.mysdk;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Service
public class MyAutowiredService {

    private String thing = "a value";

    public String getThing(String in) {
        return thing + " " + in;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        System.out.println("MyAutowiredService bean created");
    }
}
```

.

```
package org.example.mysdk;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "org.example.mysdk"
})
public class SpringContext {

}
```

**Tests**

This first test fails with a `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type` exception,

```
package org.example.testapp;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.example.mysdk.MyServiceConfiguration;
import org.example.mysdk.MyServiceImpl1;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = App.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class MySDKTest {

    @Autowired
    MyServiceImpl1 service;

    @Test
    public void test() {

        MyServiceConfiguration conf = service.getConfiguration();

        assertEquals(conf.getValue(), "this is the instance configuration");
    }

}
```

.

```
package org.example.testapp;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.example.mysdk.MySDK;
import org.example.mysdk.MyServiceConfiguration;
import org.example.mysdk.MyServiceImpl1;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "org.example.testapp"
})
public class App {

    @Bean
    public MyServiceImpl1 myServiceImpl1() {

        MyServiceConfiguration configuration = new MyServiceConfiguration();
        configuration.setValue("this is the instance configuration");

        return MySDK.getService(MyServiceImpl1.class, configuration);
    }
}
```

and this test succeeds,

```
package org.example.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.example.mysdk.MySDK;
import org.example.mysdk.MyServiceConfiguration;
import org.example.mysdk.MyServiceImpl1;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MySDKTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        MyServiceConfiguration configuration = new MyServiceConfiguration();
        configuration.setValue("this is the instance configuration");

        MyServiceImpl1 service = MySDK.getService(MyServiceImpl1.class, configuration);

        assertEquals(service.getConfiguration().getValue(), "this is the instance configuration");

    }

}
```

If I've gone about this the completely wrong way I'm happy to hear suggestions of how this should be done differently!

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify two files.

First `App.java`, it should scan for `"org.example.mysdk"` package to inject `myAutowiredService` in abstract class `MyService`, If not it has to be created in `App.java`. And the name of the `MyServiceImpl`1 bean must be different from `myServiceImpl1` as it will conflict.

```
package org.example.testapp;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.example.mysdk.MySDK;
import org.example.mysdk.MyServiceConfiguration;
import org.example.mysdk.MyServiceImpl1;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "org.example.testapp", "org.example.mysdk"
})
public class App {

    @Bean
    public MyServiceImpl1 myServiceImpl() {

        MyServiceConfiguration configuration = new MyServiceConfiguration();
        configuration.setValue("this is the instance configuration");

        return MySDK.getService(MyServiceImpl1.class, configuration);
    }
}
```

Then secondly in `MySDKTest.java` should inject `myServiceImpl` which was created in `App.java`

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.example.mysdk.MyServiceConfiguration;
import org.example.mysdk.MyServiceImpl1;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = App.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class MySDKTest {

    @Autowired
    MyServiceImpl1 myServiceImpl;

    @Test
    public void createOxiAccountService() {     

        MyServiceConfiguration conf = myServiceImpl.getConfiguration();

        assertEquals(conf.getValue(), "this is the instance configuration");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @shazin, I was wanting to have two completely independent Spring contexts though (basically I don't want the SDK user to know/care the library is using Spring internally). Is there any way to maintain a separation of concerns between the two contexts?